# Generate excel chart with values form a different sheet

Tags: c#, charts, export-to-excel

I need to create en excel sheet with multiple charts but I don't want to put the data in the same sheet and I can't find code on how this is done.

So how can I set a chart's range from a different sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wish to achieve here are two options. Lets say you already added a chart to the worksheet and you wish to connect it to some data from the worksheet "Sheet2".

a) You can set the charts SourceData. This will set the data for all the categories and series at once:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Item["Sheet2"];
chart.SetSourceData(worksheet.Range["A1:B10"]);
```

b) Or you can add series to a chart and set the values for those series. Here is an example how to set the values of one series to some range on a different worksheet.

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Item["Sheet2"];
var seriesCollection = chart.SeriesCollection();
Series series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
series.Values = worksheet.Range["A1:A10"];
```